# Regular expression allow more than amount in {}

Tags: vb.net

I have a regular expression with the {} brackets specifying the minimum amount it must have e.g.

[a-zA-Z]{2}

How can I make it so that it can have more than 2, but no less.

Answer (score 2):

The extra comma seems to do it.

```
[a-zA-Z]{2,}
```

I tested this on [www.regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com/).  And used this cheat sheet: http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/